On わたくし referring to the third person in Early Middle Japanese
In The Cambridge Handbook of Japanese Linguistics, on page 36 to be exact, the following is written:

The NJ speaker reference watakushi ('he'/'she' in EMJ) [...] came to be used from LMJ.

NJ refers to Modern Japanese, EMJ to Early Middle Japanese and LMJ to Late Middle Japanese. Intrigued by the idea of わたくし referring to the third person, I sent an e-mail to the professor who wrote this chapter in the book to check if this was a typo, but I never received an answer.
Is there any source attesting to わたくし ever referring to the third person? I am specifically asking either for a source either proving or disproving this claim, and if none can be found, at least for clear supporting evidence.

My main source for dictionary stuff is the 日本国語大辞典【にほんこくごだいじてん】 ("NKD").  I've got a dead-tree version of the abridged second-edition, but I mostly use the one available publicly online at Kotobank, a Japanese resource aggregator website that includes entries from multiple reference works.
If we look at the NKD entry for 私【わたくし】 here, and focus on the [ 2 ] 〘 代名詞詞 〙 section, we see:

自称。男女ともに丁寧な言い方として、多く目上の人に対して用いる。また、今日では、改まった言い方をする時などにも用いる。
Self-reference / first-person.  Often used [when speaking] with social superiors, as a means of polite speaking by both males and females.  Today, also used in cases such as formal speaking.

This use is dated by the NKD entry from at least 1280.
I see no mention anywhere of third-person use for the watakushi reading.  I do see what might be construable as potentially third-person use for the shi reading further down that same page:

④ 女性が、その姉妹の夫を呼ぶ称。
(4) Form of reference used by a female in reference to / when addressing the husband of a sister.

But for watakushi, from what I can find, this was never used as a third-person pronoun.
See also this older post of mine about the derivation of the term watakushi.

Thank you so much, this fulfills what I asked for in the initial question so I will validate this answer, though any further discussion is very welcome.
